# Getting Null value from 1 class to other after storing value object

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-volley

I have Authentication class which have method Auth with 2 arguments.
after calling that method a volley request generated and response catch through other function because of aSync. that object is a Static object and accessible in other class but that shows null always after making object or initializing it onCreate of activity.

Let check my Authenticate class:

```
public class Authenticate {
    private static final String URL = "http://allskkc/zaigham/idsrs_authentication.php";
    public static JSONObject finalresult;

    public Authenticate() {
    }

    public static void Auth(String IEMI, String PIN) throws TimeoutException {
        final JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        finalresult = new JSONObject();
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Splash.context);
        try {
            params.put("iemi", IEMI);
            params.put("pin", PIN);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("params to server", params.toString());
        JsonObjectRequest jsOBJRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, URL, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("response from server", response.toString());
                    ftn(response);
               }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Response error",error.toString());
                }
            });
        queue.add(jsOBJRequest);
    }

    public static void ftn(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        finalresult = jsonObject;
        Log.e("as", "Response in ftn() = " + finalresult.toString());
    }
}
```

final **finalresult** have value when I call that Auth() method but in my Login class it shows {}

let check my method call:

```
try {
    Authenticate.Auth("358607051299527","1122");
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.e("as","Prefrences Saved");
Log.e("as","My final result = "+Authenticate.finalresult.toString());
```

I attached my Log.e Image that may help more to understand.
[image]

Comment: why did you take a screenshot of the error instead of copy-pasting it?

Answer (score 1):

You can see in your logs that application tries to get the result of request before request is done. Network request is asynchronous, it is done on background thread.

You should get the result after request is finished in some sort of callback.

Comment: How i fix that @sergey